# How to correctly understand behavior of RxJava's groupBy?

Tags: java, functional-programming, rx-java, reactivex

I'm pretty new to RxJava and FP in general. I want to write a code to join two `Observable`s. Let's say we have two sets of integers:

- `[0..4]` with key selector as modulo of `2`, giving `(key, value) = {(0,0), (1,1), (0,2),...}`
- `[0..9]` with key selector as modulo of `3`, giving `(key, value) = {(0,0), (1,1), (2,2), (0,3), (1,4),...}`

My steps to join them are as follows:

1. Group each set by its keys. The 1st set creates two groups with keys `0` and `1`. The 2nd creates three groups with keys `0`, `1` and `2`.
2. Make a Cartesian product of two sets of groups, giving 6 pairs of groups in total with keys: `0-0`, `0-1`, `0-2`, `1-0`, `1-1`, `1-2`.
3. Filter only those pairs that have same keys on both sides, leaving only `0-0` and `1-1`.
4. Within each pair, make a Cartesian product of left and right groups.

Below is the helper class to calculate Cartesian product:

```
public class Cross<TLeft, TRight, R> implements Observable.Transformer<TLeft, R> {
    private Observable<TRight>      _right;
    private Func2<TLeft, TRight, R> _resultSelector;

    public Cross(Observable<TRight> right, Func2<TLeft, TRight, R> resultSelector) {
        _right = right;
        _resultSelector = resultSelector;
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<R> call(Observable<TLeft> left) {
        return left.flatMap(l -> _right.map(r -> _resultSelector.call(l, r)));
    }
}
```

And here's the code to join:

```
Observable.range(0, 5).groupBy(i -> i % 2)
        .compose(new Cross<>(Observable.range(0, 10).groupBy(i -> i % 3), ImmutablePair::new))
        .filter(pair -> pair.left.getKey().equals(pair.right.getKey()))
        .flatMap(pair -> pair.left.compose(new Cross<>(pair.right, ImmutablePair::new)))
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

However, the output is not correct:

```
(0,0)
(0,3)
(0,6)
(0,9)
(1,1)
(1,4)
(1,7)
```

If I remove the line containing `filter`, there'll be no result at all. The correct output should be just like running this:

```
Observable.range(0, 5)
        .compose(new Cross<>(Observable.range(0, 10), ImmutablePair::new))
        .filter(pair -> pair.left % 2 == pair.right % 3)
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

which gives:

```
(0,0)
(0,3)
(0,6)
(0,9)
(1,1)
(1,4)
(1,7)
(2,0)
(2,3)
(2,6)
(2,9)
(3,1)
(3,4)
(3,7)
(4,0)
(4,3)
(4,6)
(4,9)
```

Could someone explain the behavior? Many thanks.

Note: I use `org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.ImmutablePair` in case you wonder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that this setting tries to subscribe to a group multiple times which is not allowed. You'd see the exception with `subscribe(System.out::println, Throwable::printStackTrace);` overload, which is always advised to use over the other. Here is the fixed example that allows reuse at the expense of another layer of ImmutablePair:

```
Func1<Integer, Integer> m2 = i -> i % 2;
Func1<Integer, Integer> m3 = i -> i % 3;

Observable<ImmutablePair<Integer, Observable<Integer>>> g2 = 
        Observable.range(0, 5).groupBy(m2).map(g -> new ImmutablePair<>(g.getKey(), g.cache()));
Observable<ImmutablePair<Integer, Observable<Integer>>> g3 = 
        Observable.range(0, 10).groupBy(m3).map(g -> new ImmutablePair<>(g.getKey(), g.cache()));

Observable<ImmutablePair<ImmutablePair<Integer, Observable<Integer>>, ImmutablePair<Integer, Observable<Integer>>>> x1 
= g2.compose(new Cross<>(g3, ImmutablePair::new));

Observable<ImmutablePair<ImmutablePair<Integer, Observable<Integer>>, ImmutablePair<Integer, Observable<Integer>>>> x2 
= x1.filter(pair -> pair.left.getKey().equals(pair.right.getKey()));


Observable<ImmutablePair<Integer, Integer>> o = x2.flatMap(pair -> 
pair.left.right.compose(new Cross<>(pair.right.right, ImmutablePair::new)));

o.subscribe(System.out::println, Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

(I'm sorry about the long types, Eclipse has all sorts of inference problems if I try to inline them instead of having a local variable)

Comment: Cool, it actually works! I still wonder how to know if a GroupedObservable is subscribed to multiple times? Is it a best practice to always `cache` each group?

Comment: It's not easy to tell because the subscription may be hidden inside an operator. One way is to listen for the exception it produces. Using `cache` works best for short sequences as it caches everything indefinitely. Sometimes this can be avoided by multicasting through `publish(Func1)` but that has its own complexities.